# If $A$ is open or closed in $(M,d)$, then $(\partial A)^\circ = \varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

> $(M,d)$ is a metric space. If $A\subseteq M$ is open or closed in $(M,d)$, then prove that $(\partial A)^\circ = \varnothing$.

We must take two cases: (i) $A$ is open (ii) $A$ is closed.
In either case, we must show that the **interior** of the **boundary** of $A$ is empty.

**My work:**

1. Let $A$ be open. We want to argue that $(\partial A)^\circ = \emptyset$. Suppose there exists $y\in (\partial A)^\circ$. Then $y\in \partial A$, and there exists some $\epsilon_y > 0$ s.t. $B(y,\epsilon_y)\subset \partial A$. Since $y\in\partial A$, we have $B(y,\epsilon_y)\cap A\neq \emptyset$ and $B(y,\epsilon_y)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$. I don't know if this helps but we can also say that $\partial A\cap A\neq \emptyset$.
2. Let $A$ be closed. Then $A^c$ is open. Hoping that the above part would be complete, we get $(\partial A^c)^\circ = \emptyset$. Does this help?

How do I complete my proof attempts - and are there other possibly nicer ways of approaching this? Thanks a lot!

P.S. I came across [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247746/show-that-if-a-is-a-open-set-or-a-closed-set-then-int-partial-a-emptyset) but I haven't seen many of the results stated by the OP there.

Comment: for the interior of $\partial A$, you need $B(x, \varepsilon)\subseteq \partial A$ instead of $A$, no?

Comment: You're right, I'll fix that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both cases you state that there exists some $\epsilon_y\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $B(y,\epsilon_y)\subset A$. This is never true, as long as $y\in\partial A\implies y\not\in Aº$. So you are having the same proof in both cases because you introduce that fact that is a contradiction always.

You can argue it using that $B(y,\epsilon_y)\subset\partial A$.

If $A$ is closed, then $\partial A\subset A$. This means that $y\in Aº$, because $B(y,\epsilon_y)\subset \partial A\subset A$. This is a contradiction because $B(y,\epsilon_y)\cap (M\setminus A)\neq\emptyset$
.

If $A$ is open, then $B(y,\epsilon_y)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Using that $B(y,\epsilon_y)\subset\partial A$ and $A=Aº$, we get $\partial A\cap Aº\neq\emptyset$, which is also a contradiction.

Comment: I'm looking at your edit. Now it's all correct. $\partial A\cap A=\emptyset$ does really help. Also, $(\partial A^c)º=\emptyset$ helps too, because you can observe that $\partial A=\partial A^c$.